# How to specify a CRAN mirror to install R packages in Jupyter Notebook (R kernel)

Tags: r, kernel, package, jupyter-notebook

I'm having a problem installing a package for Jupyter Notebook R kernel...

The message is clear:

[image]

Question:

How do I set up or specify a mirror?

Answer (score 3):

Never mind... It's as easy as:

```
install.packages("mvtnorm", repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
require(mvtnorm)
```